# Node.JS HTTP Request - Separate The Callback Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, callback

As it is right now, callbacks for Node HTTP requests have to be anonymous function inside the request like so...

```
http.request(params, function(res){
    let data = "";

    res.on("data", function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", function() {
        console.log(data);
    });
}).end();
```

I would like to separate the callback into it's own declared function from within either the same or a different file... like so...

```
function handleData(res) {
    let data = "";

    res.on("data", function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on("end", function(){
        console.log(data);
    });
}

https.request(params, handleData(res));
```

Is it possible to do this? There are no clear answers anywhere. I feel as if I am the first person to try this. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Try `https.request(params, handleData)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be like this:

```
function handleResponse(res) {...yourcode...};
http.request(params, handleResponse).end();
```

or this:

```
const handleResponse = function (res) {...yourcode...};
http.request(params, handleResponse).end();
```

or

```
const handleResponse = res => {...yourcode...};
http.request(params, handleResponse).end();
```

or

```
const handleResponse = res => {...yourcode...};
const request = http.request(params);
request.end();
request.on('response', handleResponse);
```

JavaScript and Node.js are really flexible.

Answer (score 0):

elclanrs' comment turns out to be the solutuion, ofcourse when you add .end() to the end of the line of code he supplied.

ex.

```
http.request(params, handleData).end();
```

I am left with another question which is "Why would I not have to supply parenthesis when passing that function through the request?" I thought it should look more like

```
handleData()
```

Either way, thank you to Mr. enclanrs!